Comparing force-carrying particles
Why do electromagnetic, strong, and weak forces have spin-1 mediators, while gravity's hypothesized mediator has spin 2?
This question aims to explore the fundamental differences between gravity and other fundamental forces, focusing on why their force-carrying particles have different spins. I am not asking about the technical derivation of the graviton's spin from the Einstein-Hilbert action, but rather seeking to understand the physical or theoretical reasons behind this spin difference across forces.

Well, the source of the gravitational field is the stress energy tensor (which is a spin two object) instead of a Lie algebra valued current (which is a spin one object).

@Neutralino You need the opposite charges for dipole (spin-1) interactions. In gravity only one attractive charge exists, so only quadrupole (spin-2) interactions are possible.

There's different levels of sophistication you could give to this question, but at the most basic level: empirically, general relativity is an extremely successful theory of gravity and agrees with observations every time we can test it. So, we tend to trust it's predictions as a reasonable, default hypothesis even when we cannot directly verify them.
General relativity predicts gravitational waves have a spin-2 character. While we've never directly measured the polarization (beyond ruling out some extreme, strawman possibilities), many other predictions of GR with respect to gravitational waves have turned out to be correct (such as the spin-down rate of the Hulse-Taylor pulsar, the direct detection of gravitational waves by LIGO/Virgo from compact binary systems, the speed of gravitational waves, etc). According to the normal rules of quantization, classical gravitational waves become gravitons. So we expect spin-2 polarized classical gravitational waves to correspond to a spin-2 graviton after quantization.

This seems to be more explaining why we believe that the graviton has spin 2, rather than why it is spin-2.

IIRC "agrees with observations every time we can test it" is true but has one catch: we cannot test it precisely enough in a range wide enough. For example according to the Wiki the measurement of acceleration of free fall has at best the accuracy 10e-11 while Schwarzschield's modification rs/r has the order of magnitude 10e-13.

From a theoretical point of view you can see this as the fact that the 3 standard model interactions are forces (they generate 1D displacements), while in general relativity gravity exerts deformations* (which are described roughly as 2D displacements).
1D displacements are described by vectors (i.e. spin-1 objects) while deformations are described by particular rank-2 tensors (i.e. spin-2 objects). This is the reason.
Why gravity does exerts those deformations instead of forces and is so different is yet to discover.

*Deformations are intended, roughly, as the application of force in 2 different directions, usually not collinear, so that it deforms the path and shape of objects immersed in the gravitational field

“Why gravity does exerts those deformations instead of forces and is so different is yet to discover.” - No, it is a common knowledge why there are no dipole (spin-1) gravitational waves. In the simplest case of spherical symmetry the Birkhoff theorem explains this.

@safesphere yes i know that, it's just a different way of saying the same concept. What i meant as something to discover is why all of this apply only to gravity and not to other forces, or equivalently why general relativity differs so much with yang-mills theory

Because gravity has only one type of charge - attractive.

@safesphere that is a synonimous of spin-2 (weinberg explains this very well), they are all different ways of saying the same thing, but why gravity it is the way it is, it's still under research :)

Why gravity is only attractive is given experimentally and explained by General Relativity. There is no mystery here. So It is unclear what exactly you see as “unknown” or “not understood” about gravity or what specific research you refer to. “Spin-2” in itself is a quantum thing, but its reasons are purely classical and there is nothing unknown about gravity at the classical level.

@safesphere What is yet unknown is the reason why gravity is the only spin-2 interaction while all others are spin-1, equivalently why gravity is the only interaction not described by a Yang-Mills theory, equivalently why only gravity is sourced by the energy-momentum-stress tensor and not by a gauge current, and so on. Those are all equivalent statements, mathematically all equivalent, and we know that those are true experimentally, but we don't know why gravity is treated so differently by nature. We know that it is experimentally and, again, we know HOW differently is treated, but not why.

I see your point. It seems to assume that the nature has an obligation to have all its interactions be of the gauge type. To me though it is more amazing that there are more than one interactions of the same type. I would expect the nature to have all its interactions be totally different. So I would counter your point with this one: it is still unknown why there is more than one gauge interaction in nature, which is surprising and unexpected :) More seriously though all other interactions happen on the background (spacetime) while gravity is the background and thus is naturally different.

And ultimately the reason of why the spacetime background doesn’t have opposite charges is that time is not reversible. This restriction doesn’t affect other interactions.

I agree, nature does not need to have all the same interactions, and i also think that the answer to "why" questions is not very a physical argument, physics respond to how and not to why, in my opinion. We can ask physics how things behave, but we cannot ask why nature is the way it is, in mi view. I included that sentence only because it was in the first sentence of OP question.

Asking why gravity acts differently is like asking why the gauge group is exactly $SU(3)×SU(2)×U(1)$ and not some other group. For now, not a physics question but more a philosophical one, at least to me :)
